# libusb: get Device by serial number

Tags: libusb

libusb lets you find a device by it's vendor and product ID. But what if I have several devices with the same VID and PID attached, and want to get a handle to one of them by knowing it's serial number? There is a `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid`, but no `libusb_open_device_with_serial` or similar. Would I have to crawl though the full device list (`libusb_get_device_list`) or is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think crawling through the device list is the only way here. You could copy the code from `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid`, as that is precisely what this function does.